# Consulta sqlite para obtener todos los valores menores o mayores que un numero

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 "SELECT * FROM "+Utilidades.TABLA_COMPONENTES+ " WHERE "
 +Utilidades.CAMPO_EXISTENCIA+ " <= '"+numero.getText().toString()+"'",null
```

Me sale solo un resultado, busco que me de una lista con los resultados menores que "numero". Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

RESUELTO:  El problema era que la comparacion estaba mal elaborada ya que
para que me de un resultado la comparacion debe de ser entre dos valores Integer.  Este es la comparacion correcta:

min = Integer.parseInt(numero.getText().toString().trim());

Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Utilidades.TABLA_COMPONENTES+ " WHERE CAST ("+Utilidades.CAMPO_EXISTENCIA+" AS INTEGER)  <= '"+min+"'",null);

Comment: ¿Acaso hay más de una fila que cumpla el criterio? ¿Cómo manejas los resultados obtenidos?

Comment: he provado con numeros distintos pero solo me da un resultado,y claro los resultados entran en un arraylist y lo plasmo en un list view

Comment: La consulta parece estar bien, habria que ver la cantida de registros que trae, en caso que sean mas de uno habria que ver como estas llenando tu lista

Comment: Hola agrega por favor la información que te requieren los miembros de la comunidad, revisa [ask], saludos.